# Terraform - Pass in Variable to "Source" Parameter

Tags: github, terraform

I'm using Terraform in a modular fashion in order to build out my infrastructure. I do this by having a configuration file that calls in the different modules. I want to pass an infrastructure variable which picks up what tagged version of the Github repository the application should be building out. Most importantly I'm trying to figure out how to make a concatenation of a string happen in the "source" variable of the configuration file.

```
module "athenaelb" {

   source = "${concat("git::https://github.com/ORG/REPONAME.git?ref=",var.infra_version)}"

   aws_access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"

   aws_secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"

   aws_region = "${var.aws_region}"

   availability_zones = "${var.availability_zones}"

   subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"

   security_group = "${var.athenaelb_security_group}"

   branch_name = "${var.branch_name}"

   env = "${var.env}"

   sns_topic = "${var.sns_topic}"

   s3_bucket = "${var.elb_s3_bucket}"

   athena_elb_sns_topic = "${var.athena_elb_sns_topic}"

   infra_version = "${var.infra_version}"

}
```

I want it to compile and for the source to look like this (for example): git::https://github.com/ORG/REPONAME.git?ref=v1

Anyone have any thoughts on how to make this work?

Thanks,
Keren

Comment: P.S. sorry for the awful formatting... couldn't submit this as a code block bc Stack Overflow was complaining about the formatting...

Comment: Its not supported yet. Please check - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1439

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible currently in Terraform itself.

The only way to achieve something like this is to use a separate script to interact with the git repository that Terraform clones into a subdirectory of the `.terraform/modules` directory and switch it to a different tag depending on which version you need. This is non-ideal since Terraform organizes these into directories based on a hash of the module path, but if you can identify the module in question it is safe to run `git checkout` within these repositories as long as you do not run `terraform get` again afterwards.

For more details and discussion on this issue, see [issue #1439 in Terraform's issue tracker](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1439), where this feature was requested.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I ended up running a couple of bash commands to overwrite the end of the source URL with a specific tag based on what I pass in.

Comment: Is this available with Terraform Enterprise at least?

Comment: I don't think it is

Answer (score 0):

You could use envsubst or python jinja and use these wrapper scripts in your pipeline deploy script to actually build the scripts from .envsubst and .jinja files before your terraform plan/apply

https://github.com/uvoo/process-templates/tree/main/scripts

I wish terraform would support this but my guess is they never will so just add some simple functions/files into deploy scripts which is usually the best way to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Terragrunt offers the possibly to parameterise its **own** source referencing.

As this is only usable to parameterise an existing module, probably this is not what was asked for in the question. This answer is therefore to clarify on @Braden Wrights reply and avoid research for others.

As there is no way terragrunt "replaces" all source references in terraform code, it just can template its own reference for terraform source code. An example can be found [here](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terragrunt-architecture-dry/#using-exposed-includes-to-override-common-configurations).

Answer (score -1):

Terragrunt supports using variables for module sources

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).